# Error al instalar paquete con Pacman en Linux From Scratch 10.1

Tags: linux

Tengo los siguientes errores:

Al actualizar paquetes, todo correcto.

> ```
> (lfs chroot) root:/sources/curl-7.88.1# pacman -Su
> :: Iniciando actualización completa del sistema...
>  ...el sistema ya está actualizado.
> ```

Al instalar:
(Una larga lista)
zstd: /usr/bin/zstdgrep existe en el sistema de archivos
zstd: /usr/bin/zstdless existe en el sistema de archivos
zstd: /usr/bin/zstdmt existe en el sistema de archivos
zstd: /usr/include/zdict.h existe en el sistema de archivos
zstd: /usr/include/zstd.h existe en el sistema de archivos
zstd: /usr/include/zstd_errors.h existe en el sistema de archivos
zstd: /usr/lib/libzstd.so existe en el sistema de archivos
zstd: /usr/lib/pkgconfig/libzstd.pc existe en el sistema de archivos
file: /usr/bin/file existe en el sistema de archivos
file: /usr/include/magic.h existe en el sistema de archivos
file: /usr/lib/libmagic.so existe en el sistema de archivos
file: /usr/lib/libmagic.so.1 existe en el sistema de archivos
file: /usr/lib/libmagic.so.1.0.0 existe en el sistema de archivos
file: /usr/lib/pkgconfig/libmagic.pc existe en el sistema de archivos
Ocurrieron errores, por lo que no se actualizarán los paquetes

Con --overwrite='*':

```
(lfs chroot) root:/sources/curl-7.88.1# pacman -S nano --overwrite='*'
advertencia: nano-7.2-1 está actualizado -- reinstalándolo
resolviendo dependencias...
buscando conflictos entre paquetes...

Paquetes (16) bash-5.1.016-3  bzip2-1.0.8-5  file-5.44-3  filesystem-2023.01.31-1  gcc-libs-12.2.1-2  glibc-2.37-2  iana-etc-20230306-1  libseccomp-2.5.4-1  linux-api-headers-6.1.9-1  lz4-1:1.9.4-1  readline-8.2.001-2  tzdata-2022g-2
              xz-5.4.2-1  zlib-1:1.2.13-2  zstd-1.5.4-1  nano-7.2-1

Tamaño total de la instalación:  221,06 MiB
Tamaño neto tras actualizar:     218,55 MiB

:: ¿Continuar con la instalación? [S/n]
(16/16) verificando la integridad de los paquetes                                                                                              [#######################################################################################] 100%
(16/16) cargando los archivos de los paquetes                                                                                                  [#######################################################################################] 100%
(16/16) comprobando conflictos entre archivos                                                                                                  [#######################################################################################] 100%
error: no se pudo realizar la operación (archivos en conflicto)
filesystem: /bin existe en el sistema de archivos
filesystem: /lib existe en el sistema de archivos
filesystem: /lib64 existe en el sistema de archivos
filesystem: /sbin existe en el sistema de archivos
filesystem: /usr/local/share/man existe en el sistema de archivos
filesystem: /usr/sbin existe en el sistema de archivos
filesystem: /var/mail existe en el sistema de archivos
Ocurrieron errores, por lo que no se actualizarán los paquetes
```

Utilizo Pacman 6.0.2.